# How to return in C# and access from Ajax a navigation property of a returned object model?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, database, include

I have two tables in the database:

```
public partial class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public int Department { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department1 { get; set; }
}
```

In C# I get the Employee like this

```
public JsonResult GetSome()
{
    CompanyEntities dbc = new CompanyEntities();
    dbc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return Json(dbc.Employees.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I receive it in ajax:

```
        $("#btnSome").on("click", function () {
            $("#tb").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/AjaxData/GetSome",
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (i, el) {
                        $("#some").append(el.Name);
                    });
                },
                fail: function () { $("#error").append("No data"); }
            });
        });
```

It prints the names as expected, and also I can access all the other properties that represent the columns of the `Employee` table (in the database).

I need to access the department name that the `Employee` instance belongs to. For that I need to access the navigation property `Department1` of the `Employee` instance. So I changed iteration to this: (**but it doesn't print anything**)

```
 $.each(data, function (i, el) {
       $("#some").append(el.Department1.DepName);
});
```

Then I included `Department1` to the return data like this: (**but it still doesn't print anything**)

```
CompanyEntities dbc = new CompanyEntities();
dbc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
return Json(dbc.Employees.Include("Department1").ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

So: How to return in C# and access from Ajax a navigation property of a returned object model?

Comment: Because the entity framework uses lazy loading , it wouldnt load it until you access it in the c# code...so first access it before you pass it to the Json

Comment: @DanHunex But `Include("Department1")` causes eager loading

Answer (score 0):

Your code works great. It does not load it until you make a request to it. You misunderstood I think lazy loading...it happens only on the server , you cannot tell EF to do lazy loading from javascript( accessing navigation from javascript does tell EF to do lazy loading). As far as you need the Departement1, navigation , you have to do eager loading when you access from c#

```
return json(dc.Employees.Include(e=>e.Department1), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You have to use the directive  `using System.Data.Entity;`

I have attached the javascript debug output on chrome

[image]

Comment: I updated the return line of code to match this answer, but the compiler underlined (red) this part `e => e.Department1` and it says "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: You have to use the directive using System.Data.Entity

Comment: My ajax is working correctly when getting the data **without** including `Department1`. But after updating it like this answer, I also added the directive `using System.Data.Entity;`. After that updating; ajax method doesn't work at all. when I open the developer tools in Chrome I found this error: _GET http://localhost:2960/AjaxData/GetEmployees 500 (Internal Server Error)_